# 'Cash Account' cannot be empty

Tags: acumatica

When trying to create a new Customer using the REST API, it throws the following exception when PUT at the endpoint https://my.site/entity/Default/17.200.001/Customer

```
PX.Data.PXException: Error:  'Cash Account' cannot be empty.

PX.Data.PXOuterException: Error: Inserting 'Customer Payment Method' record raised at least one error. Please review the errors. 

at PX.Data.PXUIFieldAttribute.CommandPreparing(PXCache sender, PXCommandPreparingEventArgs e) 
at PX.Data.PXCache.OnCommandPreparing(String name, Object row, Object value, PXDBOperation operation, Type table, FieldDescription& description) 
at PX.Data.PXTableAttribute.PrepareParametersForInsert(PXCache sender, Object row, Type[] tables, ISqlDialect dialect, Boolean audit, List`1[] pars) 
at PX.Data.PXTableAttribute.PersistInserted(PXCache sender, Object row) 
at PX.Data.PXCache`1.PersistInserted(Object row) 
at PX.Data.PXCache`1.Persist(PXDBOperation operation) 
at PX.Data.PXGraph.Persist(Type cacheType, PXDBOperation operation) 
at PX.Data.PXGraph.Persist() 
at PX.Objects.CR.BusinessAccountGraphBase`3.Persist() 
at PX.Objects.AR.CustomerMaint.Persist() 
at PX.Data.PXSave`1.d__2.MoveNext() 
at PX.Data.PXAction`1.d__31.MoveNext() 
at PX.Data.PXAction`1.d__31.MoveNext() 
at PX.Api.SyImportProcessor.SyStep.a(Object A_0, PXFilterRow[] A_1, PXFilterRow[] A_2) 
at PX.Api.SyImportProcessor.ExportTableHelper.ExportTable()
```

The JSON I'm using to create the customer is:

```
{
    "CustomerID": {
        "value": "ABCD1234"
    },
    "CustomerName": {
        "value": "TEST CUSTOMER"
    },
    "CustomerClass": {
        "value": "01"
    },
    "StatementCycleId": {
        "value": "01"
    },
    "ShippingAddressSameAsMain": {
        "value": true
    },
    "CashAccount": {
        "value": "BANAMEXMN"
    },
    "MainContact": {
        "DisplayName": {
            "value": "TEST CUSTOMER"
        },
        "Email": {
            "value": "a@b.com"
        },
        "Address": {
            "AddressLine1": {
                "value": "Test test"
            },
            "AddressLine2": {
                "value": "Test test"
            },
            "City": {
                "value": "Monterrey"
            },
            "State": {
                "value": "NL"
            },
            "PostalCode": {
                "value": "00300"
            },
            "Country": {
                "value": "MX"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've looked at the Endpoints screen but I can't find the CashAccount attribute under the Customer definition. The only place where I've found it is under `Customer Payment Method` but that'd be for creating a new Method, not adding the method to the customer.

Answer (score 0):

**For REST Web Services:**

You need to extend the endpoint to add the cash account field:
[image]

Then select the PaymentInstructions entity in the left pane tree view and click on Extend Entity then Populate:
[image]

This will open a popup from where you can add the cash account field:
[image]

Finally when you call web service, change the 'Default' endpoint name in URL with the one you chose for the extended endpoint:
[image]

Ex:

```
http://domain/virtual_directory/entity/DefaultPlus/
```

instead of:

```
http://domain/virtual_directory/entity/Default/
```

---

**For Screen Web Services:**

Use `Help->Web Service->Service Description` to locate the fields:

[image]

[image]

This will open the XML Web Service Description where you can see which field can be passed with JSON:
[image]

Notice that the field container is named `BillingSettingsDefaultPaymentMethod` which matches the name of the tab and group box where the `CashAccount` field is located:

[image]

The JSON pattern to pass the field in `BillingSettingsDefaultPaymentMethod` group is the same one you're already using for `MainContact`. Notice that it only populates MainContact, it doesn't create a new contact. Same applies for default payment method group, it won't create a new payment method, it will only populate the Billing Settings tab Default Payment Method group fields.

The `CashAccount` field in your request is on the top level entity (Customer/BAccount) instead of being in the `BillingSettingsDefaultPaymentMethod` group. I suspect it doesn't exists at that level so you should remove it. To confirm it doesn't exists, look a the JSON response, it should omit the invalid fields in the response. It does so silently without raising an error.

Comment: I tried adding `"BillingSettingsDefaultPaymentMethod": { "CashAccount": { "value": "BANAMEXMN" } }` and `"BillingSettings": { "DefaultPaymentMethod": { "CashAccount": { "value": "BANAMEXMN" } } }` at the same level that `MainContact` with no success, it returns the same error. I just want to populate the Main Contact Information.

Comment: On second thought I think I've mistaken the Screen with REST API. For REST API instructions are to follow the Web service entity but the PaymentInstructions doesn't contain that CashAccount field so you would need to extend the endpoint to add it. I'll write a better answer.

Comment: When you create a customer it defaults the DefaultPaymentMethod field. The error seem to imply that it gets a value that requires a validation for a non null cash account. I would think you either have to pass that non-null cash account information or choose another payment method that doesn't require cash account validation or change the configuration so it defaults to a payment method that needs no validation.

Comment: I've added instructions on adding cash account field by extending endpoint. If you prefer to try without it, I suggest you manually fill out the screen with the same information you would send with web service then try to save. It could surface the same Payment Method error if the default value requires Cash Account field and if that field doesn't populate automatically.

Comment: I see. I'm going to do it and hope it works. If it works, i'll mark it as the correct answer. Thank you.

Comment: Now It returns the following error: `Cannot deserialize the current JSON object into type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' because the type requires a JSON array to deserialize correctly. Path 'PaymentInstructions.CashAccount', line 1, position 504.` I have added `"PaymentInstructions":{"CashAccount":{"value":"BANAMEXMN"}}` at `MainContact` level. I've confirmed that the JSON is valid

Comment: You mean PaymentInstructions nested in Customer as it should be right? not nested in MainContact?

Comment: Yes, not nested in MainContact

Comment: It is a purely syntaxic error, PaymentInstructions is an array. Fixing syntax can be achieved by wrapping the value in brackets: "PaymentInstructions":[{"CashAccount":{"value":"BANAMEXMN"}}],

Comment: However I'm still having doubt about the proper entity to extend. This array seems to apply to the payment detail grid below the default payment method. You could try instead to extend BillingContact and populate on "Billing Settings -> Default Payment Method"

Comment: `"PaymentInstructions":[{"CashAccount":{"value":"BANAMEXMN"}}]` didn't work. It returned `'Cash Account' cannot be empty.` I'll try to extend BillingContact

Comment: You need to provide value that match and validate too, you should really check if the values you pass are working when you manually fill out the page. If you pass an invalid CashAccount for the default payment method it will silently validate it and make the field null if 'BANAMEXMN' is invalid. Because of that it could be a good idea to also explicitly provide DefPaymentMethod. The main issue though on my side is that I'm unsure where exactly we should extend Payment Method because it isn't available out of box.

Comment: I'll check the value too. I'll report back in a few hours.

Comment: I extended the `BillingContact` and tried again but got this error: `PX.Data.PXLockViolationException: Error: Another process has added the 'Address' record. Your changes will be lost.`

Comment: It is hard to tell what's going on. Usually that occurs when two threads are modifying the same object. Maybe you were using the web page to modify the same customer that the web service tries to modify too. Besides that, I'm not getting any of the errors you are having. I can pass PaymentInstructions without errors. At this point I would suggest trying out an Acumatica instance populated with SalesDemo data. I doubt this is gonna lead to the errors you have. You could compare configuration between instances after that. I suspect errors are due to your instance configuration.

Comment: I checked the `Address` Table and the address was created successfuly but the `BAccountID` is `-2147483647`. I used the `Profiler` to check and for some reason is using that ID when creating the records but I can't find the query that creates the customer. It search for the `CustomerID` twice and then `DECLARE @P0 AS INT = -2147483647;` to search for that `BAccountID`

Comment: That's not good at all, this means the ORM is failing to generate proper IDs for business accounts. Again very hard to understand what happens with so many errors. Do you know how that specific instance was configured?

Comment: I do not know how it was configured.

Comment: Do you think that if i delete this orphan record, it may allow me to try again without throwing the `Address locked` error?

Comment: I think your getting errors due to deployment or configuration (database). I would advise to compare behavior with a new instance deployed using SalesDemo data which is known to be properly configured. Indeed the solution might be to delete/change data in your instance.